# No se puede convertir implicitamente 'string' en Test.Address

Tags: c#

Estoy aprendiendo a usar estas clases get;set; tratando de comprender el funcionamiento de esto y en la siguiente prueba obtengo el error de conversión implicita:
Probe usando conversiones pero ninguna funciona.

```
using System;

namespace Test
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            PurchaseOrder po = new PurchaseOrder();
            Console.WriteLine(po.City = "New York");
            Console.WriteLine(po.MyAddress = "Avenue 15 Est");
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
    }
    public class PurchaseOrder
    {
        public string City { get; set; }
        public Address MyAddress;
    }
    public class Address
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MyAddrress es una clase y necesitas instanciarla y luego instanciar su propiedad:

```
po.MyAddress = new Address();
Console.WriteLine(po.MyAddress.FirstName = "Avenue 15 Est");
```

Comment: Por cierto, las clases también pueden tener get/set -> "public Address MyAddress { get; set; };"